# How to import a Wavefront .OBJ with Blender 2.73's bpy API?

Tags: python, import

Can someone direct me to the equivalent of the earlier `import_scene` operators - like `bpy.ops.import_scene.obj()` - in Blender 2.73?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any import/export related changes that have been made for some time.

The `bpy.ops.import_scene.obj()` operator will only be available if the Wavefront OBJ addon is enabled, check that it is enabled in User Preferences.